# Run Karma test in Docker

Tags: javascript, angular, docker, karma-runner, karma-coverage

I have a Angular project and it has some tests. I am running this project in google cloud and it is working. Tests pass in the local environment and Karma is used. Now I want to generate some test coverage reports and send that to Sonarqube. I tried several examples in the internet and failed to run the tests using Karma in Docker. I am unable to find a way to how to setup Chrome in Docker. Here is my current configurations.

karma.conf.js

```
process.env.CHROME_BIN = '/usr/bin/chromium'
module.exports = function (config) {
  config.set({
    basePath: '',
    frameworks: ['jasmine', '@angular-devkit/build-angular'],
    plugins: [
      require('karma-jasmine'),
      require('karma-chrome-launcher'),
      require('karma-jasmine-html-reporter'),
      require('karma-coverage-istanbul-reporter'),
      require('@angular-devkit/build-angular/plugins/karma')
    ],
    client: {
      clearContext: false // leave Jasmine Spec Runner output visible in browser
    },
    coverageIstanbulReporter: {
      dir: require('path').join(__dirname, './coverage/front-end'),
      reports: ['html', 'lcovonly', 'text-summary'],
      fixWebpackSourcePaths: true
    },
    reporters: ['progress', 'coverage-istanbul'],
    port: 9876,
    colors: true,
    logLevel: config.LOG_INFO,
    autoWatch: true,
    browsers: ['ChromeHeadlessNoSandbox'],
    customLaunchers: {
      ChromeHeadless: {
        base: 'Chrome',
        flags: ['--no-sandbox',
                '--headless']
      }
    },
    singleRun: true,
    restartOnFileChange: true
  });
};
```

Dockerfile

```
FROM node:12-slim as build

# Install Chrome
RUN apt update && apt install -y chromium
ENV CHROME_BIN='/usr/bin/chromium-browser'

WORKDIR /usr/src/app

COPY package*.json ./

RUN npm install -g @angular/cli@9.1.13

RUN npm install

COPY . .

RUN node --max_old_space_size=8192 ./node_modules/@angular/cli/bin/ng build --prod --output-path=dist

# use Angular CLI to trigger a test run so we have coverage data
RUN ./node_modules/.bin/ng test --watch=false --code-coverage


FROM nginx:1.17-alpine

COPY --from=build /usr/src/app/dist /usr/share/nginx/html

COPY nginx/default.conf /etc/nginx/conf.d/default.conf

EXPOSE 8080
```

Here is a part of the error message.

> Step #1: 12 01 2022 11:01:44.525:INFO [launcher]: Starting browser
> Chrome Step #1: 12 01 2022 11:01:45.792:ERROR [launcher]: Cannot start
> Chrome Step #1:
> [94:94:0112/110144.876282:ERROR:zygote_host_impl_linux.cc(89)]
> Running as root without --no-sandbox is not supported. See
> https://crbug.com/638180. Step #1:  Step #1: 12 01 2022
> 11:01:45.793:ERROR [launcher]: Chrome stdout:  Step #1: 12 01 2022
> 11:01:45.794:ERROR [launcher]: Chrome stderr:
> [94:94:0112/110144.876282:ERROR:zygote_host_impl_linux.cc(89)] Running
> as root without --no-sandbox is not supported. See
> https://crbug.com/638180. Step #1:  Step #1: 12 01 2022
> 11:01:46.071:INFO [launcher]: Trying to start Chrome again (1/2). Step
> #1: 12 01 2022 11:01:49.558:ERROR [launcher]: Cannot start Chrome Step #1:    [105:105:0112/110146.523462:ERROR:zygote_host_impl_linux.cc(89)] Running as root without --no-sandbox is not supported. See
> https://crbug.com/638180. Step #1:  Step #1: 12 01 2022
> 11:01:49.558:ERROR [launcher]: Chrome stdout:  Step #1: 12 01 2022
> 11:01:49.565:ERROR [launcher]: Chrome stderr:
> [105:105:0112/110146.523462:ERROR:zygote_host_impl_linux.cc(89)]
> Running as root without --no-sandbox is not supported. See
> https://crbug.com/638180. Step #1:  Step #1: 12 01 2022
> 11:01:50.335:INFO [launcher]: Trying to start Chrome again (2/2). Step
> #1: 12 01 2022 11:01:53.128:ERROR [launcher]: Cannot start Chrome Step #1:    [116:116:0112/110150.813860:ERROR:zygote_host_impl_linux.cc(89)] Running as root without --no-sandbox is not supported. See
> https://crbug.com/638180. Step #1:  Step #1: 12 01 2022
> 11:01:53.128:ERROR [launcher]: Chrome stdout:  Step #1: 12 01 2022
> 11:01:53.129:ERROR [launcher]: Chrome stderr:
> [116:116:0112/110150.813860:ERROR:zygote_host_impl_linux.cc(89)]
> Running as root without --no-sandbox is not supported. See
> https://crbug.com/638180. Step #1:  Step #1: 12 01 2022
> 11:01:55.535:ERROR [launcher]: Chrome failed 2 times (cannot start).
> Giving up. Step #1: The command '/bin/sh -c ./node_modules/.bin/ng
> test --watch=false --code-coverage' returned a non-zero code: 1

Comment: `Running as root without --no-sandbox is not supported.` - change the user the docker container is using to run the test, or find a way to pass that option to chrome.

Comment: @Shadow, could you tell how to do that or point some examples?

Comment: @sachith is this resolved?